# Need Help Creating Custom Sorter On ObjectListView

Tags: vb.net, sorting, objectlistview

Ok, I'm totally at a loss with this....
I think I have looked at every example and every code snippet around and still can't work out how to implement a custom sorter on my ObjectListView.

My primary column (column 0) contains numbers only (as a string) but is sorting all items by alphanumeric instead of numeric, meaning that it is doing something like this:

```
1
11
111
2
22
etc.
```

I am trying to find a relatively simple example of how to modify my ObjectListView to sort column 0 when it first loads, but I'm struggling.

I have converted over a custom class called ColumnSorter (from CodeProject) into VB and I'm calling the following delegate:

```
lvwColumnSorter = New CustomLVSorter.CustomLVSorter()


lsv_OpenTickets.CustomSorter = Sub(column As OLVColumn, order As SortOrder)
                                           lvwColumnSorter.ColumnToSort = Ticket_Status.Index
                                           lvwColumnSorter._SortModifier = CustomLVSorter.CustomLVSorter.SortModifiers.SortByText
                                           lvwColumnSorter.OrderOfSort = SortOrder.Ascending
                                           lsv_OpenTickets.ListViewItemSorter = lvwColumnSorter
                                       End Sub
```

I get no errors, but I also get no change.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, are you sure you have looked at *every* example? I think there are a lot of resources on this one.

When you're using a list, datagridview, or any main form, you can adjust it to use a custom sorter. You create a custom IComparer, i.e. the definition of how you sort something. It can be as simple as converting the string (like yours) to an int with CInt() and returning -1 or +1 if it is greater or less than the last value. This is very common.

If you need help on the basics of how to do it, of course there are always the microsoft links that give you the basics such as [Custom Sort I Comparer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321292). But there is a stack flow that also follow your problem here: [Custom sort C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321292)
It's in C#, but there are many converters on that around here.

But the *easiest* way to get around it? Convert your string list into a integer list. Then it will sort perfectly.

Comment: I agree. If you have numbers, store them as numbers, and ObjectListView will treat them perfectly